# Make ignoring Prerequisite that doesn't exist

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

`make` continues to build and says everything is up to date when my dependency files say an object depends on a header file that has moved.

If run `make -d` to capture the evaluation I see:

```
Considering target file `../build/out/src/manager.o'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `../build/out/src/manager.o'.
     No implicit rule found for `../build/out/src/manager.o'.
      Pruning file `../product/build/config/product.conf'.
      Pruning file `../build/out/opt_cc.txt'.
      Considering target file `../mem/src/manager.c'.
       Looking for an implicit rule for `../mem/src/manager.c'.
       No implicit rule found for `../mem/src/manager.c'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file `../mem/src/manager.c'.
      No need to remake target `../mem/src/manager.c'.
      Pruning file `../mem/mem.h'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `../build/out/src/manager.o'.
     Prerequisite `../product/build/config/product.conf' is older than target `../build/out/src/manager.o'.
     Prerequisite `../build/out/opt_cc.txt' is older than target `../build/out/src/manager.o'.
     Prerequisite `../mem/src/manager.c' is older than target `../build/out/src/manager.o'.
     Prerequisite `../mem/mem.h' of target `../build/out/src/manager.o' does not exist.
../build/out/src/manager.o'.
     Prerequisite `../mem/mem_in.h' is older than target `../build/out/src/manager.o'.
    No need to remake target `../build/out/src/manager.o'.
```

So make knows the file is needed and is not there but doesn't attempt to create it from a rule or fail.

```
Prerequisite `../mem/mem.h' of target `../build/out/src/manager.o' does not exist.
```

Why is this and how can I get make to not ignore this rule?

Answer (score 7):

Most likely you have implemented an automatic dependency generation method that tells make to essentially ignore those files if they don't exist, by defining a target for that file without a rule.  When I have this makefile:

```
foo: foo.h ; @echo make $@ from $^
```

And no `foo.h` then make tells me:

```
$ make
make: **** No rule to make target 'foo.h', needed by 'foo'.  Stop.
```

But, if I have *this* makefile:

```
foo: foo.h ; @echo make $@ from $^
foo.h:
```

Now make is perfectly happy:

```
$ make
make foo from foo.h
```

That's a documented behavior that many auto-dependency generation utilities rely on: if you look in your generated dependency makefiles you'll see one of those empty targets for every header file.

The idea is that given correct dependency information there should never be a way to rename or delete a header file without modifying some other source or header file, which would cause the object file to be rebuilt anyway (hence recreating the dependency information correctly for the next time).

Comment: The dependency file is just "../build/out/src/manager.o : ../mem/mem.h". Running make with -p I find make has decided the header is an intermediate prerequisite? Even when crafting a target for that particular header file. That target isn't run

Comment: I seem to have this working now by defining a rule '%.h : deps' with an empty command and where deps is a phony target

Comment: From the make manual: A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if it is, its recipe will be run every time make goes to update that file.

Checked for versions 3.81 and current editions.

Comment: @TJOlaes I'm not sure how that relates to this question/answer?  There are no phony targets here.

Comment: I was replying to @Oliver's comment about his workaround, not your answer.

Comment: It's 2023 now and I'm using Make 4.1.  If I have a rule like `%.h: ;` there is a clear trace in the `make -d` log that the header file is missing, and that it must be remade and that it was successfully remade, and that the target which depended on the missing header must also be remade!  It does not say anything like that the target need not be updated.  This could be a difference between 4.1 and whatever OP was using in 2014.

Answer (score 5):

The fix I discovered is to use *static pattern rules* instead of *pattern rules*.  Pattern rules look like this:

```
%.o : %.c
    *recipe here*
```

Static pattern rules only apply to an explicit list of target files like this:

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c
    *recipe here*
```

where the variable `OBJECTS` is defined earlier in the makefile to be a list of target files (separated by spaces), for example:

```
OBJECTS := src/fileA.c src/fileB.c src/fileC.c
```

Note that you can use the various `make` utility functions to build that list of target files.  For example, `$(wildcard pattern)`, `$(addsuffix)`, etc.

You don't show the relevant parts of your makefile, so I can't be sure this will fix your situation.  But I was getting the same symptoms of `make` ignoring non-existant prerequisites, and the same message from `make -d` about "Prerequisite does not exist" but then `make` does nothing to create the prerequisite.

Note that `make` contains about 90 built-in implicit rules, most of which are pattern rules.  So even if your makefile has no pattern rules, this could still be affecting you.

I noticed a few things:

1. Asking to explicitly make the prerequisite works.  This shows that `make` knows how to build the prerequisite.
2. Adding an explicit target statement (not using a pattern rule) for a particular file seemed to solve the problem.  (But of course only for that one target... writing a rule for each of 100's of targets is unworkable).
3. In my research I kept encountering statements about how `make`'s behavior differs if there is an explicit target or not.
4. Turning off the implicit rules database with `make -r` did not help.

My guess why this works is that static pattern rules are a form of explicit target statements for the entire list of targets.

For the particular case that I was investigating, the target file already exists, and the (non-existant) prerequisite is not actually needed to build the target, it is only needed at runtime.  So perhaps `make` is correct about not needing to build the prerequisite in order to build the target.  If you are only asking to build the target, then make will do the minimum necessary to accomplish that.

<s>It still seems like a bug in `make`.  But it's probably just a mis-understanding on my part,</s> I'm no `make` expert.

**Update: (March 16, 2016).**  My current understanding is that `make` regarded these prerequisite files as *intermediate files* and therefore does not care about creating them when the target file already exists.  `Make` treats intermediate files as "second class citizens", it only makes them when needed for creating the "first class citizens" which are the explicit target defined in the makefile, or goals requested as arguments to `make` on the command line.

By using *static pattern rules* (instead of *pattern rules*) those files now are listed as explicit targets and are therefore not intermediate files but are "first class citizens" which are created and updated whenever necessary.

BTW, this also explains why using `.SECONDARY` with no prerequisites doesn't help. Doing that prevents intermediate files from being deleted, but they are still regarded as intermediate so `make` will not create them unless they are needed to make a target or goal.

Comment: To add to this (three years later...), the [GNU Make manual's](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) info on _Chained Rules_ explains the issue, matching the description above. `Make` considers patterned-matched targets to be `intermediates`, which it may ignore (and even delete) when making "real" targets. 
You can still define an implicit rule, but for intermediates that you really want rebuilt, you must have an explicit target for it.

Comment: It is not true that you must have an explicit target for any file that you don't want to be rebuilt.  Make will consider targets to be explicit if they're mentioned explicitly in the makefile, at all: it doesn't have to be as a target.  It's sufficient, for example, to list them as prerequisites of some other target: now they are no longer considered intermediate.

Comment: Regarding this: "My guess [why this works] is that static pattern rules are a form of explicit target statements for the entire list of targets.": It's correct that _static pattern rules_ belong to the category of _explicit rules_. I.e. they are not _implicit rules_ or _Pattern rules_-with-capital-_P_ - rather, the latter are a subtype of the _implicit rules_). The naming here is indeed a bit confusing. For an overview of **_GNU `make`_'s rule taxonomy**, check [this authoritative answer by @MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62901283/1562596).

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this issue in my codebase for quite a while, but could not find any cause (or solution) that matched my situation (regardless of how many searches I did on the topic). @owler, with the 'Update: (March 16,2016)' addendum, provided a hint to the actual problem with the statement "[Using `.SECONDARY` with no prerequisites] prevents intermediate files from being deleted, but they are still regarded as intermediate so make will not create them unless they are needed to make a target or goal."

There is actually an additional characteristic of 'Intermediate' files that was actually causing the problem I was having.

Here is what the makefile looked like:

```
.SECONDARY:

x.exe: x.o
        $(RECIPESTEP1)

x.o: x.c
        $(RECIPESTEP2)
```

In my case, x.o was the target that was not being rebuilt (even though it's explicitly listed as a dependency of the make goal x.exe).  More importantly (to understand the issue), x.exe did already exist.

The complete behavioral description of 'Intermediate' targets is that *'Intermediate' targets will be built **ONLY** if they are needed to build a dependent target **AND** if a dependency of the 'Intermediate' target has to be rebuilt*.  In my case, the 'x.c' file already exists and has no dependencies, so make decides 'x.c' doesn't need to be rebuilt.  Since ALL targets (including 'x.o') are marked as 'Intermediate' (due to the `.SECONDARY:` target with no dependencies) and since 'x.c' didn't need to be rebuilt, make assumes that an up to date 'x.o' was already used to build 'x.exe' (because 'x.exe' already exists). Therefore, make does not (re)build 'x.o'.

In the end, it was @Owler's comment and (careful) review of the https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html reference page that resulted in discovering the solution.

NOTE that I have presented a simplified makefile, but in the actual makefile, x.o was built from an implicit rule based on x.c - static pattern rules did not resolve the issue I was having.

The solution for me was to remove the `.SECONDARY:` target.  Going forward, the plan is to specify `.SECONDARY:` only with specific dependencies if necessary.