# GNU make seems to ignore non-terminal match-anything rules for intermediate files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following files in a directory:

FP01.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    long double ld = 0.1L; // long double constant (L or l suffix)
    scanf("%Lf", &ld);
    return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -rR

# the default target
.PHONY: all
all: FP01.elf

%.elf: %
    cp $< $@

# prevents non-terminal match-anything rules from matching target '%.c'
# see section 10.5.5 of GNU make manual
%.c:

# a non-terminal match-anything rule
%: %.c
    gcc -Wall -g $< -o $@
```

If `FP01` does not exist, running `make` gives the following output:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'FP01.elf', needed by 'all'. Stop.
```

However, if I run the following commands before `make`, then everything works as expected:

```
$ touch FP01
$ touch FP01.c
$ make
gcc -Wall -g FP01.c -o FP01
cp FP01 FP01.elf
```

Am I missing something or there is a bug in GNU make?

`make --version` gives the following output:

```
GNU make 4.1
Built for i686-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Fundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: ...
...
```

---

EDIT:

It seems that making match-anything rule terminal somehow fixes the problem, but I want to use built-in rule to generate FP01 if possible and unfortunately it is non-terminal.

Another thing is that I believe that non-terminal rule should work so using terminal rule doesn't actually solve the problem as I still don't know whether the bug is in make or in my "mental makefile parser".

Comment: This seems similar to a situation where using static pattern rules helped.  See [Make ignoring Prerequisite that doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964228/make-ignoring-prerequisite-that-doesnt-exist/34983297#34983297)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, I'd have to look more deeply into it.  But the simple way to fix your problem is to set the match-anything pattern rule that compiles from the `.c` file as terminal, which is how it should be (unless you're generating the source files from somewhere else):

```
%:: %.c
        cp $< $@

$ make
cp FP01.c FP01
cp FP01 FP01.elf
rm FP01
```

Comment: There's something funny going on with the `%` prerequisite, from the debug output it looks like make recursively matches it with the same rule it's used in, dropping the match-anything rule.

Comment: For sure it works, but it doesn't answer the question, see my comment under John Graham-Cumming's answer. Another thing is that I want FP01.elf to be the output of gcc not just a copy of FP01.c

Comment: @user657267 There's nothing special about the `%` prerequisite -- changing it to `FP01` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @AleksanderZ. You're right, I assumed it might be the `%` as it's not something you see in the wild, but it's just ignoring the match-anything rule.

Comment: Well, I just used `cp` here so I could use `touch FP01.c` to create the file instead of real C code.  Clearly the command that's invoked in the recipe is irrelevant to testing the makefile behavior so I often use simple commands like `touch` and `cp` to create minimal examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `::` on the `% : %.c` rule because you actually want that to be a terminal match-anything rule (since you don't need the `.c` file to be built):

```
MAKEFLAGS += -rR

.PHONY: all
all: FP01.elf

%.elf: % ; cp $< $@
% :: %.c ; gcc -Wall -g $< -o $@
```

Note that I used the `;` form for the recipes here because it's easier to copy and paste because no need to worry about tabs.

Comment: Ok, it works, but: 1st I simplified it a bit: I want built-in rule to be used to generate FP01 from FP01.c if possible and for obvious reason I cannot modify it. 2nd I still don't understand why non-terminal rule doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `FP01` as a prerequisite of `.INTERMEDIATE` (special built-in target) seems to make it work (no need to modify the match-anything rule). Just another workaround.

```
MAKEFLAGS += -rR

# the default goal
.PHONY all
all: FP01.elf

%.elf: % ; cp $< $@

# prevents non-terminal match-anything rules from matching target '%.c'
# see section 10.5.5 of GNU make manual
%.c:

# a non-terminal match-anything rule
%: %.c ; gcc -Wall -g $< -o $@

.INTERMEDIATE: FP01
```

Comment: Even just making it a regular target works, `FP01:`.