# GNU make - transform every prerequisite into target (implicitly)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have another `make`-like tool that produces an XML as an artifact after parsing my makefile which I'll then further process with Python.

It'd simplify things for me - a lot - if I could have `make` consider every single prerequisite to be an actual target because then this other tool
will classify each and every file as a "job".

This is a fragment of my makefile:

```
.obj/eventlookupmodel.o: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/PROJ/src/AL2HMIBridge/LookupModels/eventlookupmodel.cpp C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\PROJ\src\AL2HMIBridge\LookupModels\eventlookupmodel.h \
        C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/PROJ/qt5binaries/include/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel.h \
        C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/PROJ/qt5binaries/include/QtCore/qvariant.h \
        ...
```

I'd want for `make` to think I have a dummy rule for each prerequisite such as below:

```
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/PROJ/qt5binaries/include/QtCore/qvariant.h: 
     @echo target pre= $@

 C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/PROJ/qt5binaries/include/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel.h: 
    @echo target pre=$@

C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/PROJ/src/AL2HMIBridge/LookupModels/eventlookupmodel.cpp :
    @echo target pre=$@

C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\PROJ\src\AL2HMIBridge\LookupModels\eventlookupmodel.h:
    @echo target pre=$@
```

I don't care about the exact form of the rule just that each file is considered an actual target.

My method of passing in this rule would be by setting the MAKEFILES variable like so

`make all MAKEFILES=Dummy.mk`

with `Dummy.mk` containing this rule so that I do not modify the makefiles.

I've tried the following so far.

Dummy.mk:

```
%.h: 
    @echo header xyz = $@

%: 
    @echo other xyz= $@
```

This partially works.

I run `make all --trace --print-data-base MAKEFILES=Dummy.mk` and I can see that 
`make` does "bind" the `%.h:` rule to the header files. In the `--print-data-base section`, I see that rule being assigned to the header files.

```
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/QNX_SDK/target/qnx6/usr/include/stddef.h:
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/QNX_SDK/target/qnx6/usr/include/stddef'
#  Last modified 2016-05-27 12:39:16
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
#  recipe to execute (from '@$(QMAKE) top_builddir=C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/../lib/armle-v7/release/ top_srcdir=C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/ -Wall CONFIG+=release CONFIG+=qnx_build_release_with_symbols CONFIG+=rtc_build -o Makefile C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/HmiLogging/HmiLogging.pro
', line 2):
@echo header xyz = $@
```

**However, I do NOT see the "echo header xyz $@"-rule being executed.**

Regarding the `%:` rule, it is neither executed for the `.cpp` files nor "bound" to them in the `--print-data-base` section.
However, it is bound and executed for existing targets which have no suffix i.e.

```
all: library binary

binary: | library
ifs:    | library
```

For the `%:` rule, the reason for this behavior is because of [**10.5.5 Match-Anything Pattern Rules:** If you do not mark the match-anything rule as terminal, then it is non-terminal. A non-terminal match-anything rule cannot apply to a file name that indicates a specific type of data. A file name indicates a specific type of data if some non-match-anything implicit rule target matches it.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make#Match_002dAnything-Rules)

If I make it non-terminal - no double colon - then the rule doesn't apply to built-in types like `.cpp`unless I un-define the built-in rules that negate my intended `%:` rule.

If I make it terminal, ["it does not apply unless its prerequisites actually exist"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make#Match_002dAnything-Rules). But a `.h` or `.cpp` doesn't technically have prerequisites; can I just create a dummy file and have that as its prerequisite?

***NOTE: This has NOTHING to do with `gcc -M` generation. Yes the `-M` option would help in the specific case of header and source files but this question is for more generic targets and prerequisites that already exist in the makefile when `make` is launched.***

Comment: So you are actually asking how to make every header file in the working directory a prerequisite of... some target. Is that right?

Comment: @Beta no not a prereq. I want to make EVERY file that `make` is aware of to have an empty rule i.e. `AnyFile:` SO THAT the rule that I define in `ImplTarget.mk`.

Comment: @Beta if some file, like a `.cpp` already has a rule, the additional "empty rule" will have no effect.

Comment: @Beta I'm trying to accomplish what `gcc -E -M -Mp` accomplishes but in particular, what the `-MP` flag accomplishes: in addition to emitting a rule that states what headers a `.cpp` is dependent on, it ADDITIONALLy emits those same headers one line at a time as an empty target i.e. header file followed by colon. Example is `header1:`, `header2:`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211171/gnu-make-rule-to-get-list-of-all-prerequisites-of-every-target

Comment: You say you want to accomplish what `gcc -MP` accomplishes, but you can't actually use `gcc -MP` because your boss won't allow major modifications to the makefiles. That's like saying you want to drive several nails into the wall, just as if you were using a hammer, but you can't use a hammer because your boss doesn't want nails in the wall. *What are you actually trying to do?*

Comment: @Beta `The purpose of ImplTargets.mk is to get make to execute something for each headerfile present. Obviously, right now it's just a dummy statement.`

Comment: @Beta whatever files `make` can "see" i.e. targets, prerequisites I want it to create and execute recipes as if they are  targets.

Comment: @Beta I redid the question. Should be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating *static pattern rules* for the header files.  See one of the answers to [Make ignoring Prerequisite that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964228/make-ignoring-prerequisite-that-doesnt-exist).

Static pattern rules only apply to an explicit list of target files like this:

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c
    *recipe here*
```

where the variable `OBJECTS` is defined earlier in the makefile to be a list of target files (separated by spaces), for example:

```
OBJECTS := src/fileA.c src/fileB.c src/fileC.c
```

Note that you can use the various `make` utility functions to build that list of target files.  For example, `$(wildcard pattern)`, `$(addsuffix)`, etc.

You should also ensure that the recipe "touches" the header file to change the timestamp.

I've found that using static pattern rules instead of pattern rules fixes problems where make doesn’t build prerequisites that don’t exist, or deletes files that you want.

---

Here is an example of using `wildcard` to copy files from one directory to another.

```
# Copy images to build/images
img_files := $(wildcard src/images/*.png src/images/*.gif src/images/*.jpg \
src/images/*.mp3)

build_images := $(subst src/,$(BUILD_DIR)/,$(img_files))
$(build_images): $(BUILD_DIR)/images/% : src/images/%
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    cp -v -a $< $@
```

There are other `make` functions like `addprefix` that could be used to generate a more complex file specification.

Comment: Ok will try when I get into work on Tuesday. Thanks.

Comment: This won't help me by itself. The file list I need is of the prerequisites like `.h`, `.cpp`, etc. `wildcard` only operates on the current directory and my headers are scattered. I'll update question with example.

Comment: `wildcard` can generate file names for any directory if you give it the proper argument.  I'll update my answer with some examples.

Comment: Problem is that I don't the directories to hard-code them. I need `make` to do its magic and just "marshall" them for me.

Answer (score 0):

This may take a few iterations. Try:

```
%.h: null
    @echo header xyz = $@

%: null
    @echo other xyz= $@

null:
    @:
```

Comment: Works for `.h` files but the `%:` doesn't catch `.cpp` files though it *does* catch files with an extension that does NOT have a built-in rule. This is because of the following from `make` manual: `If you do not mark the match-anything rule as terminal, then it is non-terminal. A non-terminal match-anything rule cannot apply to a file name that indicates a specific type of data. A file name indicates a specific type of data if some non-match-anything implicit rule target matches it.`

Comment: I will try marking the `%:` as terminal and see what happens.

Comment: Looks like this basically works: `%:: null` \n\n `null:\n @:` but if I have no recipe for `%:: null` then `make` says `target 'null' does not exist`. `make` doc says `One choice is to mark the match-anything rule as terminal by defining it with a double colon. When a rule is terminal, it does not apply unless its prerequisites actually exist. Prerequisites that could be made with other implicit rules are not good enough.` I think that's why it's doing this.

Comment: Looks like `null` [might have some special meaning on windows that it doesn't on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38252249/4784683)