# GNU Make - terminal rules and keyword "null"

Tags: bash, makefile, cmd, gnu-make, msys

**BACKGROUND**

This is related to my question [GNU make - transform every prerequisite into target (implicitly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153956/gnu-make-transform-every-prerequisite-into-target-implicitly)

I've posted *this* question because it's interesting and may be useful by itself - to understand `make` - and I don't want it to get lost in the "original" question.

**INFO**

I have a file `Dummy.mk`:

```
%:: null
    @:

null:
    @:
```

which I pass to my `make` as `make all MAKEFILES=Dummy.mk`.

When I replace `null` with `saflkjsaflkjdsa`,

```
%:: saflkjsaflkjdsa
    @:

saflkjsaflkjdsa:
    @:
```

the behavior of the build was different: the rule was never executed.

The reason is because this is a ["terminal rule"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make#Match_002dAnything-Rules):

> One choice is to mark the match-anything rule as terminal by defining
>   it with a double colon. **When a rule is terminal, it does not apply
>   unless its prerequisites actually exist**. Prerequisites that could be
>   made with other implicit rules are not good enough. In other words, no
>   further chaining is allowed beyond a terminal rule.

Since `saflkjsaflkjdsa` did not exist, the rule was not executed. Ok fine I understand that.

But when I set `Dummy.mk` using the keyword `null`

```
%:: null
    @:

null:
    @:
```

the `%::` rule does execute i.e. it captures ALL targets, filenames, etc giving me outputs of the form `:2: update target <item> due to: null` where `<item>` is any filename or target that `make` reads in.

Since the rule **is** executing using `null` but not with using `saflkjsaflkjdsa`, `make` is definitely detecting `null` as "existing".

**QUESTION**

But then why do I still get the output `:5: target 'null' does not exist`?

Is that because of the OS- or shell-level peculiarities of `null` existing but not existing at the same time?

**Environment** 
* Windows 8, 64-bit 
* Make 4.2.1 (here's output of `make`

```
# GNU Make 4.2.1
# Built for Windows32
# Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
# This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
# There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
find_and_set_shell() path search set default_shell = C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/QNX_SDK/host/win32/x86/usr/bin/sh.exe
...
```

* Shell that `make` is using internally is:

```
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\Project\bld\armle-v7\release\subProj>where sh
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/QNX_SDK/host/win32/x86/usr/bin/sh.exe

C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\Project\bld\armle-v7\release\subProj>sh --help
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release-(i686-pc-msys)
Usage:  sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
        sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
        --debug
        --debugger
        --dump-po-strings
        --dump-strings
        --help
        --init-file
        --login
        --noediting
        --noprofile
        --norc
        --posix
        --protected
        --rcfile
        --restricted
        --verbose
        --version
        --wordexp
Shell options:
        -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option          (invocation only)
        -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option
Type `sh -c "help set"' for more information about shell options.
Type `sh -c help' for more information about shell builtin commands.
Use the `bashbug' command to report bugs.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is that because of the OS- or shell-level peculiarities of null existing but not existing at the same time?

Since you didn't specify which OS or shell you're using, it's impossible for us to say.  All I can say is that I tried to replicate your problem on my GNU/Linux system and couldn't: on my system no targets were built in either case (using `null` or `saflkjsaflkjdsa` made no difference)

My suspicion is you're using Windows; I have a vague recollection that `null` is special somehow on Windows.  But, I don't do Windows so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I am using Windows but I'm using a shell that's not the CMD shell.

Comment: Are you using make compiled with MSVC?  Or MinGW?  Or Cygwin?  Note that the shell you're using is mostly irrelevant: make doesn't use the shell to decide which targets are out of date.  The shell is only used once make decides that a target is out of date and wants to update it.  Here your problem is that make is checking for existence of this file and finding it even when there's no file named `null` on the disk.  ISTR there are some special devices on Windows which always appear to exist but are not real files.

Comment: In any event you should add this detail to your question and maybe add a windows tag to your question, and maybe some Windows-knowledgeable people will respond.

Comment: I updated with the shell info. I compiled my `make` with MSVC.

Comment: To make this "design pattern" platform neutral, would it be ok to replace `null` with some file that I know always exists like `$(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))`?

Comment: Your post is a bit of an XY problem.  What is it that you are actually trying to do?