# GNU make - 3.81 build fails vs 4.2.1 (4.0+?) succeeds 'cannot find library'

Tags: windows, gcc, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

**BACKGROUND**

This is related to my question [GNU make - transform every prerequisite into target (implicitly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153956/gnu-make-transform-every-prerequisite-into-target-implicitly)

**INFO**

I am running my build like so

`make all MAKEFILES=Dummy.mk`

with `make v3.81` and `make v4.2.1`

Dummy.mk:

```
%:: null
    @:

null:
    @:
```

- Windows 8, 64-bit
- Shell used by `make` is

  ```
  C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\Project\bld\armle-v7\release\subProj>sh --help
  GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release-(i686-pc-msys)
  ...
  ```

When I build with `make v3.81`, the build fails on this compile command:

```
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -lang-c++ -Wl,-rpath-link,\
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\target\qnx6/armle-v7/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,\
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\target\qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,\
C:/fs/mp/qt5/lib -Wl,-rpath,C:/fs/mp/fordhmi/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,libHmiLogging.so.1 -o\
libHmiLogging.so.1.0.0 .obj/hmiloggingcategory.o .obj/hmiloggingcategoryregistry.o\
.obj/hmiperformancelogging.o .obj/hmitracelogging.o\
-LC:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\target\qnx6/armle-v7/lib\
-LC:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\target\qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib\
-LC:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/Proj/qt5binaries/lib -lQt5Core \
-LC:/QNX650/target/qnx6/armle-v7/lib \
-LC:/QNX650/target/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -lm  
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\host\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntoarm-ld: cannot find -lQt5Core
cc: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/QNX_SDK/host/win32/x86/usr/bin/ntoarm-ld caught signal 1
make[3]: *** [C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/Proj/lib/armle-v7/release/lib/libHmiLogging.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

You're probably thinking "well you haven't told it where to find that library" but I only see this error when I run with `make 3.81` AND do `MAKEFILES=Dummy.mk`.

If I use `make 3.81` without `Dummy.mk`, there's no error. 
If I use `make 4.2.1` with or without `Dummy.mk`, there's no error.

Our project is kinda transitioning from `make v3.81` to `make v4.2.1` but stuff still has to work with `make v3.81`.

**QUESTION**

What's the cause of this error?

**NOTE**

`qcc` is the QNX version of `gcc`. It supports pretty much all `gcc` functionality.

Comment: There's no reason for this that I know of.  You'll have to debug it further.  The first thing to do is a character-by-character comparison of the linker line generated by make 3.81 and 4.2.1 and see if there's any difference.  If so tell us the difference and see if you can figure out why.  If there's no difference then you can add the `-Wl,-v` option to the link line (if qcc really does support all the functionality of GCC/binutils) to ask the linker to generate verbose output, and compare that line-by-line between what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @MadScientist what's "linker line"?

Comment: When you run the compiler front-end like `qcc` and ask it to generate an executable, instead of an object file, then it invokes the linker which links all the .o files and creates a runnable executable.  The "linker line" is the command line you show in your example output, `qcc -Vgcc_ntoarm71e ...`

Comment: Is linker line entire command line or only the part that has linker arguments?

Comment: I'm not sure which arguments you may be _not_ considering "linker arguments", but when the compiler front-end needs to invoke the linker then it will pass all the arguments to the linker, in almost all cases, so yes, it's the entire command line.