# Why does gnu make ignore missing dependencies for pattern rules?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

A minimal example:

```
%.bar: missing_file.pckl
   @echo executed
```

When I type `make foo.bar`, `make` says "Nothing to be done". Why? The `missing_file.pckl` does not exist and neither does a rule for it. Shouldn't this raise an error? (I know that you can circumvent this by making the rule static - I just want to understand the reasoning.)

On a side note - I'm trying to understand the logic behind `make` better - , what's the difference between pattern rules and implicit rules (the terms seem to be used interchangeably)? And what's the reason that pattern rules cannot be made phony? I read that implicit rules are intended to produce files - but to me it makes equally sense to me to use pattern rules for phony targets.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, a pattern rule is an implicit rule that is written out in the makefile. I agree that the terminology could be better. (I am not posting an Answer because I have a good idea why you get `Nothing to be done`, but not why Make behaves the way it does when `.PHONY` meets `%.bar`.)

Comment: You could also post a partial answer, I'd be grateful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pattern rule is an implicit rule.  But [suffix rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) are also implicit rules.

There are two basic types of rules in a makefile: explicit rules and implicit rules.  Explicit rules consist of rules for explicit targets, and also static pattern rules (this is definitely confusing, that "static pattern rules" are actually explicit, but they are: they are just shorthand for writing lots of explicit rules).  Implicit rules consist of pattern rules and suffix rules.

Think of an implicit rule as a template.  It doesn't actually define any targets at all.  It only gives templates for how a target (which matches the pattern/suffix) could be created.  If your makefile contains only implicit rules then when you type `make` it won't do anything, because your makefile hasn't actually defined any targets... it's only created templates.

It's important to understand that there can be *many* templates that could build the same target.  Even the built-in make rules provide many different ways to build an object file, for example: by using a C compiler, a C++ compiler, a FORTRAN compiler, etc.  And users can add their own.

If no explicit rule is found for a target, then make will start searching for an implicit rule.  It may look through many of them, and you sure wouldn't want to see an error or message for each one that didn't match!

This pretty much gives the answer to all your questions, but to sum up:

The reason you get this message is that make searched all the implicit rules that could be used to build that target, and it didn't find one that could be used (the one you provided doesn't work because the prerequisite doesn't exist... but make doesn't consider that an error because it's just one way the target could be built.  People actually use this very handy feature sometimes!!)  So it said, "I don't know how to build that target".

Of course, make could generate more details here.  It could say "oh, I happen to know that there's only one implicit rule that could match so I can be more specific about why that one rule didn't work and say that the prerequisite was missing".  But that would be confusing if you had two implicit rules that might match.  Or, it could list all the possible prerequisites that it couldn't find.  Or something.  I'm not sure any of those would really be an improvement in general.  They would be better in some situations, and super-annoying in other situations.

The reason you can't apply `.PHONY` to a pattern rule is that a pattern rule isn't a target.  Of course, a reasonable enhancement would be to allow `.PHONY` to take a pattern and then apply phoniness to all targets that match that pattern.  But, that enhancement hasn't been implemented for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you four your answer! -- Okay, I get that you don't want to list all the implicit rules that didn't work. But when I type `make foo.bar`, I expect this to be handled just like a target. So if it finds only implicit rules that don't match in the end, it should give an error "no rule to make target [...]". Or "I don't know how to built that target", as you said. But "nothing to be done" implies that everything's fine IMO - because that's the same message that you get for up-to-date targets.

Comment: Okay, maybe now I get it -- because the file *exists* and matching (implicit) rule can be found that actually can be applied, `make` pretends that there are no rules for this file at all and just sees it as an input. Correct? (Sorry, I forgot that `foo.bar` existed already. If that weren't the case then "nothing to be done" really wouldn't make any sense.)

Comment: Right.  It's as if you typed `make foo.c` in a directory with a source file `foo.c`.  There's nothing make needs to do with that file.

Comment: @MadScientist this answer has very useful general information on _GNU `make`_'s "rule taxonomy" - I had been looking for exactly that for some time until I found this gem. Any chance something like the above could find its way into the official docs? Also including a summary in the form of a hierarchy, e.g. as an indented bullet list, would also be great (`*explicit rules **ordinary **static pattern; *implicit rules **pattern **suffix` etc.). The docs make plenty references to such terminology when specifying behaviour etc., so as a user it's key to grasp these definitions and distinctions.