# Make removes files as intermediate

Tags: makefile

When trying to organize the compilation output into a build directory, `make` keeps removing object files. The `Makefile` is:

```
MPI_INSTALLATION=/home/gkaf/Software/MPI
IDIR=$(MPI_INSTALLATION)/include
LDIR=$(MPI_INSTALLATION)/lib

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)
LDFLAGS=-L$(LDIR) -Wl,-rpath=$(LDIR)

BUILD_DIR=build
OBJ_DIR=$(BUILD_DIR)/obj
BIN_DIR=$(BUILD_DIR)/bin

SRC_DIR=src

LIBS=-lmpi

.PHONY: all
all: test-mpi

.PHONY: test-mpi
test-mpi: prepare $(BIN_DIR)/test-mpi

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(BIN_DIR)/%: $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

prepare: $(BUILD_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
        mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
$(OBJ_DIR):
        mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
$(BIN_DIR):
        mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

The object file `build/obj/test-mpi.o` generated during the compilation is deleted after the executable `build/bin/test-mpi` is created.

I believe that `make` treats `build/obj/test-mpi.o` as an [intermediate file](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html). However, I was expecting that `build/obj/test-mpi.o` would not be treated as an intermediate file since it appears explicitly in the target `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c` and gnu make documentation states that "ordinarily, a file cannot be intermediate if it is mentioned in the makefile as a target or prerequisite".

This behavior [has been reported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517190/what-causes-make-to-delete-intermediate-files) in a similar issue, but I believe that in both cases the files should not be treated as intermediate since they appear in a target. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just how is it that `build/obj/test-mpi.o` appears explicitly in `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c`?

Comment: The question is, why do you care that the object file disappeared?

Comment: I want to maintain the object files to avoid unnecessary recompilation. In this case the executable depends on a single object file, but if the executable later depends on multiple object files, I would like to recompile only the object files with changes.

Comment: If the executable depends on multiple object files, then you'll have to write a rule in the makefile that lists them all.  Once you write such a rule, then the object files will no longer be considered intermediate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe that make treats build/obj/test-mpi.o as an intermediate file.

Yes, that looks right.

> However, I was expecting that `build/obj/test-mpi.o` would not be treated as an intermediate file since it appears explicitly in the target `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c` [...]

Given that `$(OBJ_DIR)` expands to `build/obj`, the *pattern* `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o` *matches* `build/obj/test-mpi.o`. That's the opposite of `build/obj/test-mpi.o` appearing explicitly.

Even so, you have read the GNU `make` documentation correctly: `make` would not consider `build/obj/test-mpi.o` to be an intermediate file if it was mentioned as a target or prerequisite of some other rule.  But it isn't.  If `make` builds that file at all, it is entirely `make`'s idea, notwithstanding the fact that you set the stage for it to come to that decision.  This is exactly what it means to be an intermediate file.

> Am I missing something?

Apparently you are missing what it means for a file to be "mentioned in" a makefile, as the GNU docs put it.  It means that the file's name appears literally in the makefile text, after macro expansion, as a target or prerequisite of a rule.  Example:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/test-mpi: $(OBJ_DIR)/test-mpi.o
```

or

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/test-mpi.o: $(SRC_DIR)/test-mpi.c
```

Matching a target or prerequisite pattern of an implicit ("pattern") rule does not suffice.  In fact, it is exactly files that are generated as intermediates in chains of implicit rules that `make` aims to remove.  Implicit rules defined in the makefile are not distinguished from `make`'s built-in implicit rules in this regard.

However, although files such as the one you asked about are definitely intermediate files as GNU `make` defines that term, `make` has an additional capability here that might serve your purposes.  If you want to use a pattern to specify intermediate targets that you want to preserve, then you can do so by designating the pattern as a prerequisite of the special target `.PRECIOUS`, like so:

```
.PRECIOUS: $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o
```

Intermediate files matching such a pattern will be spared from the automatic deletion to which they otherwise they would be subject.

Comment: Very nice answer. Mentioning the [`.PRECIOUS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002ePRECIOUS-1) GNU make target could maybe be useful.

Comment: Adding the line `.PRECIOUS: $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o` indeed prevents make from deleting the intermediate files. I chose to explicitly define the rules for each executable as it is more flexible. For instance, if the executable `test-mpi` also depends on some object file `functions.o`, I can simply extend the rule `$(BIN_DIR)/test-mpi: $(OBJ_DIR)/test-mpi.o` to `$(BIN_DIR)/test-mpi: $(OBJ_DIR)/test-mpi.o $(OBJ_DIR)/functions.o`.

Comment: Thank you, @RenaudPacalet.  I have added a brief discussion of the relevant properties of `.PRECIOUS`.

Comment: I definitely don't recommend using `.PRECIOUS` in this way.  That's not what it was intended for, and it has unpleasant side-effects.  In particular, if the compiler fails or you use ^C to interrupt the build, then these object files can be left behind on the disk with "newer" timestamps so they won't be rebuilt when you re-run make.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same issue as @gkaf, and find it crazy: `make` removing an object file (that *is* mentioned in the Makefile, although implicitly) effectively defying the purpose of `make` (avoid recompilation)...
Thanks @John Bollinger to clarify the distinction implicit/explicit, and that that is the intended behavior of `make`.

A better solution than `.PRECIOUS` may be `.NOTINTERMEDIATE`, as in

```
.NOTINTERMEDIATE: $(OBJS)
```

as documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html) (you have to construct the variable `$(OBJS)` first).

Another alternative is to avoid pattern rules at all (which bring other [pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34983297/9908011)), in favor of *static pattern rules*. Something like:

```
$(OBJS) : $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c ; ...
```

This is now an explicit reference to the object file via `$(OBJS)` (I hope!), so it is not affected by the problem. Once again, the price is the need for the definition of `$(OBJS)`.

Note that the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-versus-Implicit.html) about static patterns vs patterns does not seem to mention these points (at least not explicitly ;) )